# Qual è il significato di "impastocchiare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il giardino dei Finzi-Contini*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Lui, poveretto, vorrebbe strappare al papà il permesso di riverniciare tutto quanto, restaurando e **impastocchiando** a suo piacere. Però il papà nicchia, al solito, e non si decide...

Non capisco il significato del verbo "impastocchiare" in questo brano. Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che può significare imbrogliare o inventare bugie per ingannare qualcuno, ma non sembra che questo sia il senso nel passaggio precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Mi fa pensare a “[impastrocchiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impastrocchiare/)”: non so se sia un refuso o una variante in uso a Ferrara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il gerundio “impastocchiando” sta per “impastrocchiando”, nel senso di “pasticciando”, dato che il verbo “impastrocchiare”, un  derivato dialettale del sostantivo “pastrocchio” che significa “pasticcio” usato anche in senso figurato, indica che qualcuno sta facendo dei pasticci, proprio come in questo passo del romanzo di Giorgio Bassani, dove “impastocchiando” (variante ferrarese di “impastrocchiando”) significa che Perotti, il maggiordomo tuttofare della famiglia Finzi-Contini, vorrebbe riverniciare la vecchia carrozza blu che sta nella rimessa della villa, restaurandola e magari pasticciando a suo piacimento con i colori e quindi mescolandoli, come in un pasticcio, cioè forse in una confusione di tonalità diverse.

Vedi le voci sottostanti:

- PASTROCCHIO 
  (region. sett., centr.) intruglio, pasticcio (anche in senso figurato)
  Etimologia: adattamento della voce veneta "pastrocio", affine a "pasticcio".
- IMPASTROCCHIARE
  pasticciare, mescolare.
  Etimologia:da "pastrocchio".
- IMPASTOCCHIARE
  escogitare pretesti o menzogne per ingannare altri o trarre d’impaccio sé stessi: impastocchiare delle scuse |impastocchiare qualcuno, imbrogliarlo.
  Etimologia:  deriv. di "pastocchia", col pref. in-.
- PASTOCCHIA
  fandonia, frottola con cui si cerca di trarre in inganno qualcuno.
  Etimologia:  deriv. di "pasto", dalla locuzione antica "dare pasto (o pastocchie)"= ‘raggirare’, 'imbrogliare'.

La fonte da citare è esattamente il passo in questione (“restaurando e impastocchiando a suo piacere”) scritto da Giorgio Bassani, che, nato a Bologna da famiglia ferrarese, trascorse l’infanzia e l’adolescenza proprio a Ferrara e quindi ebbe modo di usare, oltre all’Italiano,  il dialetto emiliano-ferrarese.

Come, infatti, si può facilmente notare,  è inverosimile che in “restaurando e impastocchiando a suo piacere” il verbo “impastocchiare” abbia  il significato di “imbrogliare” o “escogitare pretesti o menzogne per ingannare altri”,   mentre è del tutto plausibile che significhi “pasticciare”, cioè “impastrocchiare”.

Può darsi che esistano altre fonti scritte relative a “impastocchiare” usato al posto di “impastrocchiare”, ma credo sia arduo trovarle, perché bisognerebbe esaminare tutte le opere di scrittori di area emiliano-veneta alla ricerca di contesti simili dove “impastocchiare”  stia per “impastrocchiare”.

Per amore di precisione, devo  tuttavia citare la definizione che l’ormai datato *Nuovo dizionario dei sinonimi della lingua italiana* di Niccolò Tommaseo dà di “impastocchiare”:

> ”Dicesi di chi maneggia cose e le rimpasta senz’ordine e senza grazia. Poi, di chi dà pastocchie, cioè tende a persuadere altrui con una folla e un miscuglio  di false ragioni”

Come appare evidente, Tommaseo attribuisce a “impastocchiare” sia il significato di “impastrocchiare”/ “pasticciare”, sia quello di  “imbrogliare”/”raggirare”, mentre oggi i moderni dizionari citano “impastocchiare” e “impastrocchiare” con significati diversi.

Per la voce “impastocchiare” nel  *Nuovo dizionario dei sinonimi della lingua italiana* (pubblicato nel 1838) vedi:
https://books.google.it/books?id=mOosAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=impastocchiare+sinonimo&source=bl&ots=3ADoNHD4Kl&sig=XSAqhiCVd-YsD0JBrL1RHf8-pII&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFwtfwx9jUAhVKLsAKHQKUAkEQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=impastocchiare%20sinonimo&f=false

Comment: Grazie, quasi tutto questo sta su qualunque dizionario. Il passaggio delicato è che si tratti, come dici, di una «variante ferrarese di “impastrocchiando”». Puoi citare una fonte?

Comment: La fonte è esattamente il passo di Bassani, che trascorse l’infanzia e l’adolescenza a Ferrara e quindi usò  il dialetto emiliano-ferrarese. Per maggiori informazioni vedi l'altra mia risposta.

Comment: Sì, conosco bene Bassani, la sua vita e le sue opere, e Ferrara l'ho menzionata io stesso in un commento. Ma per spiegare un termine di un brano non puoi prendere come fonte il brano stesso. In altre parole: hai motivi indipendenti da questo brano per ritenere che a Ferrara si dica “impastocchiare” laddove in italiano standard si dice “impastrocchiare”? Altrimenti potrebbe essere un refuso, un'eccentricità di Bassani o chissà che altro.

Comment: Quindi siamo arrivati alla conclusione che *non* è una variante ferrarese, ma buon italiano, ancorché desueto, come attesta il dalmata Tommaseo.

Comment: Italiano molto desueto!